# extract neural network construction code without running the target code

Tags: python, neural-network, information-extraction

I want to extract neural network architecture definition code from python files. The following is an example NN definition code using pytorch.

```
class CNN(torch.nn.Module):

def __init__(self):
    super(CNN, self).__init__()
    # L1 ImgIn shape=(?, 28, 28, 1)
    #    Conv     -> (?, 28, 28, 32)
    #    Pool     -> (?, 14, 14, 32)
    self.layer1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
    # L2 ImgIn shape=(?, 14, 14, 32)
    #    Conv      ->(?, 14, 14, 64)
    #    Pool      ->(?, 7, 7, 64)
    self.layer2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
    # Final FC 7x7x64 inputs -> 10 outputs
    self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(7 * 7 * 64, 10, bias=True)
    torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc.weight)

def forward(self, x):
    out = self.layer1(x)
    out = self.layer2(out)
    out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)   
    out = self.fc(out)
    return out

model = CNN().to(device)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)  
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
```

Then, what I want to extract is the CNN network architecture (i.e. the CNN object or the network definition code).

**the NN architecture**

```
  CNN(
  (layer1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (layer2): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU()
    (2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  )
  (fc): Linear(in_features=3136, out_features=10, bias=True)
  )
```

**or the definition code**

```
class CNN(torch.nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        # L1 ImgIn shape=(?, 28, 28, 1)
        #    Conv     -> (?, 28, 28, 32)
        #    Pool     -> (?, 14, 14, 32)
        self.layer1 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        # L2 ImgIn shape=(?, 14, 14, 32)
        #    Conv      ->(?, 14, 14, 64)
        #    Pool      ->(?, 7, 7, 64)
        self.layer2 = torch.nn.Sequential(
            torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            torch.nn.ReLU(),
            torch.nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2))
        # Final FC 7x7x64 inputs -> 10 outputs
        self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(7 * 7 * 64, 10, bias=True)
        torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_(self.fc.weight)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)   
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

    model = CNN().to(device)
```

Any idea on how to implement this efficiently? Is there anyway to extract the desired information without running the target code?

Comment: What do you mean by "neural network architecture definition code"?

Comment: Actually, I want to extract the neural network architecture, as is supplemented in the post.